# ConcurrentHashMap of Singleton Instances

Tags: java, singleton, concurrenthashmap

I saw an answer on quora (https://www.quora.com/Can-we-create-mulitple-instances-of-singleton-classes-in-Java-if-so-how-if-not-then-why) that suggested creating a ConcurrentHashMap of Singleton instances 'keyed by an identifying string', but I'm unsure of how this would work. Here is my attempt:

```
public class SingletonClass {

static ConcurrentHashMap<String, SingletonClass> list = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SingletonClass>();

private static SingletonClass instance = null;

static String name;

public SingletonClass() {
    this.name = "";
}

public SingletonClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public SingletonClass getInstance(String key) {
    SingletonClass result = list.get(key);
    if(result == null) {
        instance = new SingletonClass(name);
        list.putIfAbsent(key, instance);
        result = instance;
    }
    return result;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And I have no idea how to proceed or how to create an instance of this and store a key,value pair in the list, and then retrieve the value again depending on the specific key? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1. Make the constructor private, 2. Create the object using `SingletonClass.getInstance("whatever");`. The `getInstance` method takes care of the singleton being a singleton as long as the constructor is private and not used anywhere else in the class.

Comment: @dan1st what if I wanted to create multiple SingletonClass objects across different classes and be able to call them?

Comment: Use one static "register" class has s map of all singletons. When created, a class calls a method in the register class that registers it or fails/gives back the object

Comment: I'm a little confused about your wording. Are you looking to instantiate multiple Singleton classes? If so, you don't. The point of a Singleton is there is only one instance of the class. If you're looking to get multiple references to that Singleton, the `getInstance()` method should be `public` and `static` so it can be called from anywhere in the program to grab the reference.

Comment: @TimHunter thanks for your response and apologies for the confusion; I did in fact mean instantiate multiple Singleton classes, and was wondering if it could be achieved? I feel I may have misinterpreted the initial answer from Quora...

Comment: Nope. Like I said, the point of a Singleton designed class is that there will only be one instance of the class in the system. From there, you would use a `getInstance()` method to pull references to that single instance into other parts of the system. If you are able to have multiple instances of a class in the system, then that class is not a Singleton designed class.

Answer (score 2):

- you are creating multiple instances, how is that a singleton then? It's not
- `getInstance()` should be static in any case
- you are using a static variable in your `getInstance()` method for no reason, you open this code to a racing condition this way (well, multiple racing conditions). And this variable is unnecessary, do everything in scope of this method
- this is not a singleton pattern, this is an [object pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) of [flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) objects - same as wrapper classes (Integer, Long etc.) in Java

The point is that, with this approach, there will be no 2 objects with the same key.

```java
// with your approach
SingletonClass one = SingletonClass.getInstance("someKey");
SingletonClass two = SingletonClass.getInstance("someKey");

System.out.println(one == two); // true, same object

// without your approach
SingletonClass three = new SingletonClass("someKey");
SingletonClass four = new SingletonClass("someKey");

System.out.println(three == four); // false, different objects
```

Saving memory, possibly time on object creation and possibly time on gc cycles.

Comment: thank you for your response - I feel I may have misinterpreted the answer from Quora regarding a ConcurrentHashMap of Singleton instances. Your examples of SingletonClass three and SingletonClass four are in-line with what I was trying to create, and then being able to call those methods from other classes.